# node.name is not working in Component.ts in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-tree-component

I need to get the root node name of a tree in angular, but node.name is getting "Node" as the value.

Below is my .html code part:

```
<mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl"
 class="example-tree">
    <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodeToggle 
     (click)="selectedItem = node.name;" >
        {{node.name}}
    </mat-tree-node>
    <mat-nested-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChild"
    >
        <div class="mat-tree-node">
          <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle
                  [attr.aria-label]="'Toggle ' + node.name"
                  (click)="selectedItem = node.name; NodeCollapse(node.name)">
            <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
              {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
            </mat-icon>
          </button>
          {{node.name}}
        </div>
        <div [class.example-tree-invisible]="!treeControl.isExpanded(node)"
            role="group">
          <ng-container matTreeNodeOutlet></ng-container>
      </div>
    </mat-nested-tree-node>
  </mat-tree>
```

Below is my Component.ts code containing the Method(NodeCollapse) definition which I call on Node Button-Icon Click:

```
NodeCollapse(n_name:string):void{

let nodename:string=n_name;

if(Node.name)
{
  
}
```

}

Below is my source debugger from Browser:
[Browser Source debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ow0Ua.png)

Comment: Look at Node. Look at the type it's not related to the tree at all. It's something related to the browser. Pass the node in the call.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking another `Node`. Also, you have already passed the `node` name to the `NodeCollapse` method.

```
let nodename:string=n_name;

// its wrong
if(Node.name)
{
  
}
```

If you want to access the `name` property of `node` entity, it's better to pass directly the `node` to the `NodeCollapse` method. Just use the `n_name` inside your method.

I have prepared [an example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jsgbgx?file=app%2Ftree-nested-overview-example.ts).